# How to Display name from login show to other pages

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have to take the name. of users who have logged in to display on my ejs page. I can do it on the admin page, but if I can't do the same on the user page, an error occurs. I don't understand why. And I want an answer on how to fix this.

`admin.js`

```
router.get('/adminform', function (req, res, next) {
  var username = req.session.username;
  var name = req.session.name;  
  res.render('adminform', { title: 'adminform', username: username, name: name});
});
```

`user.js`

```
router.get('/userform', function (req, res, next) {
  var username = req.session.username;
  var name = req.session.name;  
  res.render('userform', { title: 'userform', username: username, name: name});
});
```

`login.js`

```
router.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
    var username = request.body.username;
    var password = request.body.password;
    if (username && password) {
        connection.query('SELECT *  FROM member WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [username, password], function(error, results, fields) {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                request.session.loggedin = true;
                request.session.username = username;
                var user = results[0]; 
                request.session.name = user.name;   
                results.map(val =>{
                        console.log(val.role);
                        if(val.role == 0){
                            console.log("admin");
                            response.redirect('/admin/adminform'); 

                        }
                        if(val.role == 1){
                            console.log("member");  
                            response.redirect('/user/userform'); 
                            
                        }
```

`.ejs`

```
<h2> Welcome <%= username %> </h2>
```

### name

Comment: Error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)



page admin not error but page user is error

Comment: Please edit your question so it includes the error, it is harder to find in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Options

1. Use a global variable instead of req.session, as each request is different.
2. Use a library that handles session e.g. express-session

Suggestions for role == 0 is unsafe, if no record found default will be admin. try use === instead of == or map integer with a string for easy readability